# Need to create the order list numbers and alphabet numbers for the title using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create the order numbers and order alphabet letters for the title using CSS.

```css
h4.heading_numberlist{
    counter-increment: list-number;
    margin-top:12.0pt;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:3.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}
h4.heading_numberlist::before{
   content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
}
```

```html
<div class="topic nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
</div>
<div class="topic nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
</div>
<div class="topic nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
</div>
```

But its not working. Expected Output is:

```
1. Services
2. Tests
3. Number
```

Meanwhile for the Alphabetic titles change into

```
A. Services
B. Tests
C. Number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment in the div not the h4

```css
h4.heading_numberlist {
  margin-top: 12.0pt;
  margin-right: 0in;
  margin-bottom: 3.0pt;
  margin-left: 0in;
  page-break-after: avoid;
  font-size: 12.0pt;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4.heading_numberlist::before {
  content: counter(list-number, upper-alpha) '. '; /* change upper-alpth with decimal for number*/
}

.topic {
  counter-increment: list-number;
}
```

```html
<div class="topic nested3">
  <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
</div>
<div class="topic nested3">
  <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
</div>
<div class="topic nested3">
  <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
</div>
```

> The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter and **includes the element's descendants and its following siblings with their descendants**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I wonder why do u need to use h4 for ordered list. Since HTML, already providing semantic tag for order list. It is support any type of order list you want.

So it might be better to make it something like this

```html
<!-- order list with alphabet -->
<ol type="A">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ol>

<!-- order list with number -->
<ol type="1">
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D thanks for the feedback. I edited my answer to include the sample for this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For numbers:

```css
h4.heading_numberlist::before {
    content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
}
```

For letters:

```css
h4.heading_numberlist::before {
    content: counter(list-number, upper-alpha) '. ';
}
```

You don't need the `content` in your `h4.heading_numberlist` after adding this.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/a671bkd9/1/) is an example JSFiddle demonstrating the `upper-alpha` example.

Comment: Please see here https://jsfiddle.net/x81aoder/1/. I'm getting 1 for all the title.

Comment: I have edited the question by using your answer. Please see

Answer (score -1):

It might be better to use an ordered list element for this purpose. You can change the bullet type with CSS too.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha; /* remove this to show regular numbers */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Tests</li>
  <li>Number</li>
</ol>
```