# Wordpress text block list type is not changing

Tags: wordpress, textblock

Try to change list type of text block in word press. I change the text block using `text mode` not `visual mode`

add `type="A"` in `<ol>` tag . But after save changes, it doesn't work. How to implement it correctly?

In the image below i want to change `1.Informasi Pribadi` to `A.Informasi Pribadi`

https://ibb.co/DKCHtDB

https://ibb.co/NLPSxgY

Comment: your link is not working.

Comment: According to this it should be very simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62909879/7262739 

This is assuming, that the template you are using does not overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

This might point you in the right direction. Usually you will be changing list styles with either HTML or CSS.
With HTML there are `<ul>` (un ordered) and `<ol>` (ordered) lists.

Then you can change their bullet points with some CSS like in this tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp